# AJAX requesting is always returning the GET method which is making my php script return NULL values, why is that happening?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am building a webpage that has an input form, I don't want the submit button to reload the page, so I need to use an AJAX request in order to able to send the inputs to my SQL db. However when I try to use the AJAX request, the request submitted to the PHP file is GET instead of POST. This causes my php file to malfunction and always returns NULL values to the SQL db.

This is my js code:

```
`document.querySelector('#contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form submitted');
    var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#contact-form'));
    console.log('Form data:', formData);
  
    // Send the form data to the PHP script using AJAX
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'submit-contact-form.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  
    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('Response received:', xhr.responseText);
      // Handle the response from the server
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var contactContainer = document.querySelector('.contact-container');
        var thankYou = document.querySelector('#thank-you');
        document.getElementById('contact-form').style.display = 'none';
        setTimeout(function() {
            thankYou.style.display = 'block';
            contactContainer.style.textAlign = 'center';
        setTimeout(function() {
            contactContainer.style.textAlign = 'center';
            thankYou.style.animation = 'fadeIn 1s';
        }, 5);
      }, 200);

    // Animate the transition
    setTimeout(function() {
        contactContainer.style.transition = 'height 0.5s ease-in-out';
        contactContainer.style.height = thankYou.offsetHeight + 'px';
      }, 200);
        
      } else {
        // Handle errors
        console.log('Error:', xhr.statusText);
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log('There was an error submitting the form.');
      };
      console.log(formData.get('name'), formData.get('email'), formData.get('message'));

    xhr.send(formData);
    
    });
```

I added some debugging codes in order to monitor what is happening and why I am getting the Bad Request 400 error, the xhr payload has the correct values, but the response always returns NULL values.

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
require('config/db_connect.php');
// Check if the form was submitted
// var_dump($_POST);
// die();
echo ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Get the form data
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : "";

    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($email);
    var_dump($message);
    

    // Validate the form data
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = "Name is required";
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = "Email is required";
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid email format";
    }
    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = "Message is required";
    }

    // If there are no errors, save the form data to the database
    if (empty($errors)) {
        // Connect to the databas

        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Prepare and bind the SQL statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact_messages (name, email, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $message);

        // Execute the SQL statement
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Form submitted successfully";
        } else {
            error_log("Error: " . $stmt->error);
            echo "Error submitting form. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close the database connection
        $stmt->close();
        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {
        // If there are errors, send them back to the client
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: xhr.open('POST will definitely send a post. Have you checked your browser's network tool to verify what is actually happening

Comment: @ADyson the request method in the network tool is POST, but the ECHO function in the php file shows GET, also, I tried changing the If request method condition to GET, and that made the function run. When I returned it to POST, then I would get the Bad Request 400 error again

Comment: And you're seeing that in the `console.log('Response received:', xhr.responseText);` console log, is that what you're saying? Because I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: @ADyson the response is always in NULL values

Comment: That doesn't answer the very specific thing that I asked. You said `the ECHO function in the php file shows`, so I asked you to clarify specifically where you're seeing it. Are you seeing those nulls in the console, in the "Response received..." line?

Comment: P.S. Is there any reason you're using `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');` when you're just sending basic form data, without any files? When you send a formData object, XHR will generally set the correct content-type for you anyway, so it's best not to try and second-guess it. I wonder if this is related to your issue. Try removing that line and testing it again.

Comment: @ADyson Oh, im sorry I didn't understand your question, no I see the GET method when I load the submit-contact-form.php page since this is a separate file than the one containing the form. As for the nulls I am seeing them when I check the response tab when I view the request in the browser's network tool.

Comment: `since this is a separate file than the one containing the form`...well then obviously that one is not going to be able to echo the form data which was posted into a different request. Form data doesn't persist across PHP scripts when they are executed in response to different HTTP requests. It sounds like you've made two requests to `submit-contact-form.php` - an XHR POST request, and another separate GET request. It's not really clear why you've done that.

Comment: `As for the nulls I am seeing them when I check the response tab when I view the request in the browser's network tool`....which request? The XHR POST request, or the GET?